# CallKit can not open app by social profile at contacts detail page

Tags: ios, callkit

When I set

```
config.supportedHandleTypes = NSSet setWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber], nil];
```

I can open my app from iOS contacts by long pressing the **call** button and choose my app from the menu.

When there is a new social profile named **my app name**, nothing happens when I tapped it.

I have tried WhatsApp And DingDing and some other apps, they can be opened by tapping the social profile.

Please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAzNf.jpg):

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: Include socialprofile also inside supportedHandleTypes and try.

Comment: @RJVKumar but there are only 3 types, no socialprofiles: CXHandleTypeGeneric = 1, 
CXHandleTypePhoneNumber = 2, 
CXHandleTypeEmailAddress = 3

Comment: Sorry. It is CXHandleTypeGeneric

Comment: @RJVKumar Thanks for your reply, but I have added the 3 types all, and not work.
does your app work in this scene?

Comment: @RJVKumar Finally I found the reason, If config.supportsVideo is YES, my app can not be opened by tapping the social profile.otherwise if set config.supportsVideo=NO, it works.
Perhaps it is a iOS feature or bug?

Comment: I didn't tested with video. So I don't have any idea.